# When to use alloc init

Tags: objective-c, arrays, pointers, allocation

The following two examples each seem to work just fine. In example 1, ***widget*** is created before the while loop:

```
-(int)compareWidgets { // Example 1

    int count = 0;
    NSMutableArray *widgetsCopy = [self.widgets mutableCopy];

    Widgets *widget = [[Widgets alloc]init]; // HERE ? or...

    while (widgetsCopy.count) {
        widget = [widgetsCopy lastObject]; 
        [widgetsCopy removeLastObject];
        for (Widgets *compareWidget in widgetsCopy)
            if (compareWidget.value == widget.value)
                count += 1;
    }
    return count;
```

}

In example 2, *widget* is created inside the while loop...

```
-(int)compareWidgets { // Example 2

    int count = 0;
    NSMutableArray *widgetsCopy = [self.widgets mutableCopy];

    while (widgetsCopy.count) {
        Widgets *widget = [widgetsCopy lastObject]; // HERE ?
        [widgetsCopy removeLastObject];
        for (Widgets *compareWidget in widgetsCopy)
            if (compareWidget.value == widget.value)
                count += 1;
    }
    return count;
```

}

Q1: In the example 1, *widget* is allocated/initialized just once and then it seems to be reassigned for each iteration through the array. In example 2, alloc/init is never used but *widget* is, again, successfully assigned through each iteration. Why is this possible and which example is either correct or preferable?

Q2: Also, in either case, *widget* is assigned to an array object which is immediately removed from its array: *[widgetsCopy removeLastObject]*. Since the object *widget* points to has been removed from its array, why isn't *widget* nil at this point--why does it continue to retain the correct value?

Thanks.

Comment: You should read about [the iOS memory-management basics](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/ios-memory-management-part-1). Modern iOS uses a system called ARC that eliminates a lot of boilerplate, but you still need to be familiar with the fundamentals, and judging from your question you aren’t yet.

Answer (score 1):

The first code snippet creates an object with `alloc`/`init`, and then the body of the `while` immediately releases it.

There is no need to create an object and assign it to your variable in order to make that variable "valid": you can assign the variable as long as it is in scope at the time of the assignment.

`Widget` does not become `nil` right away, because under ARC variables are `__strong` by default, so an assignment to `widget` leads to the corresponding object being retained. If you change `Widget *widget` to `__weak Widget *widget`, you would see a `nil` there, but then there would be no point in declaring that variable in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Consider pointers as being an empty box.  In the first example you put a new widget in that box.  Then the very next thing you do is empty that box and put the lastObject in that box.  The example breaks down a little since the widget is still in that array as well till you remove the last object.  ARC lets you not have to worry as much about how many boxes it is in.  Once it is taken out of the last box it will get released.